# Combine Text together in a linq Select Statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like this

```
 public class ItemImage
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

now I want to append the url portion to the Name.

// result would be  http://www.example.com/{Name}

I can do a select

```
images.Select(x => x.Name )
```

but I am not sure how I can just join the url + name in one go.

I tried

```
images.Select(x => new { fullImagePath= "http://www.example.com/" + x.Name })
```

but I just want a simple array(ie ["http://www.example.com/1.jpg","http://www.example.com/2.jpg"]

Comment: I think the concept being missed here is that the callback to Select is a *method*. You can do **anything** in it, string interpolation, concatenation, other method calls, whatever. It just has to return the "mapped" result.

Comment: Yea, I don't know how I missed trying that, I guess I thought it would have to be a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
images.Select(x => $"http://www.example.com/{x.Name}" )
```

Example:

```
var images = new List<ItemImage> {
   new ItemImage{Name = "1.jpg" },
   new ItemImage{Name = "2.jpg" }
};

var result = images.Select(x => $"http://www.example.com/{x.Name}");

// result[0] = "http://www.example.com/1.jpg"
// result[1] = "http://www.example.com/2.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# up to version 5

```
images.Select(x => string.format("http://www.example.com/{0}", x.Name))
```

In C# 6+

```
images.Select(x => $"http://www.example.com/{x.Name}" )
```